# Check if array contains more nils than other values

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, collections

Given an array with only odd counts:

```
[1,nil,nil]
[1,nil,Module,nil,2]
[1,Class.new,nil]
```

I would like to determine if there are nils or more non-nils. The approach I used was to make everything either true or false first. And then to determine if there are more true or false values:

```
[ 1,nil,nil,nil,2,3].collect {|val| !!!val }.max
#=> ArgumentError: comparison of TrueClass with false failed
```

The max method does not want to play nice with booleans. How can I accomplish this?

Now this might not be the best approach to determine whether there are more nils or non-nils, but this is the approach that I used.

Comment: Is it really the case that the array can only contain **odd** counts? Of course, for an even-length array, there could be an equal number of `nil` vs non-`nil` -- so how would you handle that? Your example of `[]` contains 0 elements; 0 is an **even** number.

Comment: I'm also unclear what the question is. The title says "**true** or **false**", your question says "**truthy** or **false**", then you say you want to count **nil** vs **non-nil**, then your code is using `!!!val` (which is surely just the same thing as `!val`?) - and is therefor actually counting the **truthy** vs **falsey** values.

Comment: What do you want the "result" of this method to be? `true`/`false`, depending on whether there are more **truthy** vs **falsey** values??

Comment: What happens when (as your case is) the true and false groups are equal?

Comment: @TomLord I clarified the question

Comment: You've now been given 3 answers, all of which are wrong, because the original question was contradictory and confusing :(

Comment: Coming upon this question after several edits had been done I was perplexed why most of the answers were simply incorrect. That's what happens when you change the question after an answer has been posted. That earns a downvote from me. Incidentally, the best answer was given by 
@sagarpandya in a comment on Andrey's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given an array with only odd counts

If by that you mean that there will always be the nonequal amount of truthy/falsey values in an array, then, first of all, `[]` is not a valid input.

And here's the solution:

```
def truthy?(array)
  falsey, truthy = array.partition(&:!)

  truthy.size > falsey.size
end
```

You can go with oneliner if you prefer:

```
def truthy?(array)
  array.partition(&:!).max_by(&:size).any?
end
```

Spec:

```
truthy?([1,nil,nil])          #=> false
truthy?([1,nil,nil,nil,2])    #=> false
truthy?([1,4,nil])            #=> true
truthy?([1,nil,nil])          #=> false
truthy?([1,nil,Module,nil,2]) #=> true
truthy?([1,Class.new,nil])    #=> true
```

It uses

- [`Enumerable#partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method;
- [`BasicObject#!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) method.

---

If you indeed intended to only calculate `nil`s, not falsey values (as it was stated in the OP):

```
def more_nils?(array)
  array.partition(&:nil?).max_by(&:size).none?
end
```

Spec:

```
more_nils?([1,nil,nil])          #=> true
more_nils?([1,nil,nil,nil,2])    #=> true
more_nils?([1,4,nil])            #=> false
more_nils?([1,nil,nil])          #=> true
more_nils?([1,nil,Module,nil,2]) #=> false
more_nils?([1,Class.new,nil])    #=> false
```

It uses [`Object#nil?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) method.

Inspired by [@pjs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104175/1772830):

```
array.sum { |el| el.nil? ? -1 : 1 }.negative?
```

Even simpler ( from @SagarPandya's comment)

```
array.count(nil) > array.compact.count
```

Comment: The question was clarified -- apparently Donoto *did* want to count `nil` vs non-`nil`; I have no idea why they decided to convert everything to `true`/`false` first. Therefore this answer (while it does address the original ambiguous question) is not correct. You should be using `element.nil?` instead of `!element`.

Comment: @TomLord added `nil` version

Comment: That is a lot of work for `arr.compact.size < arr.size / 2.0` or `arr.compact.size / arr.size.to_f < 0.5`

Comment: @engineersmnky I am not the one to call on "Ruby" way, but would you yourself approve code review if you saw `arr.compact.size < arr.size / 2.0` introducing "magic number" (`2`), operating on initial input multiple times... Well, I don't say my second and third options are any better, but I bet that most Ruby devs would accept my very first option over both you presented :) (`falsey, truthy = array.partition(&:nil?); falsey.size > truthy.size`)

Comment: `arr.count(nil) > arr.compact.count`

Comment: The question is "Check if array contains more nils than other values". There is no mention of truthy or falsy values. So why address a different question, as you did in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland check the question history :) moreover, the answer was accepted, then the question was edited

Comment: Imo, @engineersmnky and sagar both have the best approach, but I find smnky's solution a bit messy with it's unnecessary use of floating point.

Comment: Andrey, yes, I see.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree although I had also gone with `Rational(arr.compact.size,arr.size) < 0.5)` which is less "ugly" but still involves a floating point but requires less iteration

Comment: Inverse formula: `arr.size > arr.compact.size * 2`

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward solution would be:

```
def truthy?(ary)
  ary.map { |bool| bool ? 1 : -1 }.sum > 0
end
```

Map entries to +/-1 based on their truthiness, sum, and see whether the sum is positive or negative.

This can deal with empty arrays, it returns `false` in that case.

Comment: This is simpler and more efficient than the accepted answer. The accepted answer requires copying the whole array. It's easily adapted to check for nils.

Comment: could be simplified to `sum` with a block.

Comment: @Schwern : The solution by pjs is elegant, but while it doesn't require copying of the array, it still creates a temporary object of the same size, so maybe using `inject` would be better (or `sum`, as has been suggested). Another problem is, that it produces wrong results if one of the array elements is `false`. I think we should use `bool.nil? ? 1 : -1` inside the block.

Comment: `ary.map { ... }.sum` → `ary.sum { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Here another one:

```
if array.size > 2*array.compact.size
  # We have more nil than non-nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that falsy values are `nil` and `false`, and everything else is truthy (as conditional statements do), you can leverage `Object#itself` with `Array#select`.

```
irb(main):013:0> ary = [1,nil,nil,false,2]
=> [1, nil, nil, false, 2]
irb(main):014:0> ary.select(&:itself).length
=> 2
irb(main):015:0> ary.reject(&:itself).length
=> 3
```